# Is it possible to replace part of a string with the content of an include file?

Tags: php

Is it possible to replace parts of a string with the content of an include file?

For example, this is my string

```
$string = '<p>The article title goes here bla bla bla...</p>{{ADD_AUTHOR_DETAILS_}}<p>The article body goes here...</p>';
```

Basically, I want to replace `{{ADD_AUTHOR_DETAILS_}}` with the content of an `include` file. The include file contains html tags, text, etc...

Is this possible in php and if yes, how?

**EDIT**

Some are asking what's inside the include file (php file). This is a sample

```
<div class="article-author"><?php
    if ( !empty($artistphoto) ) { ?>
        <img class="round" src="<?php echo $config['path']['artist_image'] . $artistphoto; ?>" width="" height="" alt="<?php echo $artistname; ?>"><?php
    } else { ?>
        <div class="placeholder round"><span></span></div><?php
    } ?><span><a href="<?php echo $config['reference']['library_author'] . $artisthref; ?>"><?php echo $artistname; ?></a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, use `str_replace`.

Comment: That's how templating works, I believe

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do it but it really depends on what's in the include... it could just be an array of strings with things like `ADD_AUTHOR_DETAILS` as the keys - without knowing that, this question is too vague.

Comment: @CD001 I've edited my question to add a sample of the include (php file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use output buffering functions. See [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('path/to/your/file.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();

$string = '<p>The article title goes here bla bla bla...</p>{{ADD_AUTHOR_DETAILS_}}<p>The article body goes here...</p>';

echo str_replace('{{ADD_AUTHOR_DETAILS_}}', $content, $string);
```

OP said "include" not file_get_contents, though perhaps the other answer maybe what you're looking for.

Comment: I think if OP wanted to actually use `include` it would be for a PHP file.

Comment: Im only reading what the OP has said `file contains HTML tags, text, etc...` if it is a .php extension that's easily rectified.

Comment: The include file is a php file. I've tried using file_get_contents with no success. Using ob_start with a php file seems to work..

Comment: Ok, so you needed to actually run/parse the contents of the file. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: @ICanNowComment Yeah, i've edited my question to include a sample of the include php file

Answer (score 2):

You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to load the contents of a file, then use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the part of your string.

```
$myString = 'This is a lovely string... But [REPLACE_THIS]';
$fileContents = file_get_contents('my_replacement.txt');
$myString = str_replace('[REPLACE_THIS]', $fileContents, $myString);
```

Comment: I've edited my question to add a sample of the include (php file). This, i believe, will not work, but i took note, it will certainly come in handy for later...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace multiple substrings with strtr.

```
<?php

$string = '@@HEADING@@, welcome, @@BODY@@, thankyou.';
$output = strtr($string, array(
    '@@HEADING@@' => file_get_contents('/tmp/heading.txt'),
    '@@BODY@@'    => file_get_contents('/tmp/body.txt')
));

print $output;
```

Comment: what's up with the `@` massacre? xD